# ASP.NET Can't reference model from my view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem that I can't reference my model Samochody from view Index i've created. I created this model in folder called Models and all should work but it looks like i'm not as smart as i thought :D Can you guys help me with this? Here's the code

Samochody.cs model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using static WebApplication2.Models.Samochody;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class Samochody
   {
    public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime Bought { get; set; }
        public DateTime Sold { get; set; }
    }

}

public class CarDBCtxt : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

}

And Index.cshtml

```
@model Samochody.Models.Car //error here, can't find Samochody
@{
   Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is second time i have this type of error and it's from 2 different tutorials.

Comment: `WebApplication2.Models.Samochody.Car ` (but why are you using nested classes?)

Comment: Nested classes?

Comment: `class Car` is inside `class Samochody`

Comment: Hmm, yeah I see, i just write what was in tutorial convinced it was good :D I didn't notice it, guess it's from exhaust. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the namespace of your class in your index.cshtml. So it needs to be:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Samochody.Models.Car
```

or an alternative is to edit the **web.config** file in the **Views** folder and add the namespace there:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host ...
  <pages ...
   <namespaces>
     <add ...
     <add namespace="WebApplication2.Models" />
```

and then you won't need to add the namespace within each .cshtml file.

Comment: Another option would be to add this namespace to the _viewStart file, instead of the web.config.  Largely personal preference as to which one you use, as far as I know.